# Winform Application Telerik reference error not resolved

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, desktop-application, telerik-grid

[image]

I want to use Telerik with Winforms. After the build of the project, I get an error. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from the licenses.licx file, so I recommend trying the following steps from [this Telerik support article](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/details/how-to-fix-license-file-related-errors):

> you can solve them by:
>
> - Deleting the contents of the license.licx and making it read only
> - Or deleting the whole license.licx file and rebuild
> - Or right-clicking the Telerik.Web.UI.dll file in Windows Explorer, select Properties, and then click the 'Unblock' button on the General
>   tab near the bottom.
> - Or if your app is under the source control to make it ignore the license file so any changes on a developer machine won't make it into
>   the build machine or anywhere elsewhere.